# Creating row number for multiple columns?

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

I have the below data, and I want to only take one Location per Order ID ordered by the distance. This data set takes customer zips and compares to store zips and then returns the distance. I want to only choose the store they're closest to.

I have this so far:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM (
    SELECT 
    t.*,
    row_number() over(PARTITION BY orderid ORDER BY dts) rn
    FROM (
        SELECT 
        location,
        orderid,
        group1,
        group2,
        group3,
        group4,
        group5,
        custid,
        dts,
        sum(qty) AS units,
        sum(bsk) AS demand
        FROM osfdist
        GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
    ) t 
) a
```

But this just starts the increment at 1 for the first row ordered by Distane and then increments to the total number of rows. I want it to say:

```
Downtown    1
Downtown    1
Downtown    1
Downtown    1
Coastal     2
Coastal     2
Coastal     2
Coastal     2
```

etc, so I can select where `row_number=1` and only select the Downtown records.

| Location | OrderID | Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 3 | Group 4 | Group 5 | Customer ID | Distance | Qty | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Downtown | 1 | FOOTWEAR | SHOES | SHOES (LOW) | M | RUN | abc123 | 8.724497523 | 1 | 90 |
| Downtown | 1 | APPAREL | PANTS | PANTS (1/1) | F | FOO | abc123 | 8.724497523 | 1 | 22.5 |
| Downtown | 1 | FOOTWEAR | SHOES | SHOES (LOW) | U | ORI | abc123 | 8.724497523 | 1 | 55 |
| Downtown | 1 | APPAREL | SHORTS | SHORTS | M | TRA | abc123 | 8.724497523 | 3 | 50 |
| Downtown | 1 | APPAREL | PANTS | TRACK PANT | F | ORI | abc123 | 8.724497523 | 1 | 35 |
| Downtown | 1 | APPAREL | PANTS | TRACK PANT | M | ORI | abc123 | 8.724497523 | 1 | 35 |
| Downtown | 1 | FOOTWEAR | SHOES | SHOES (LOW) | M | ORI | abc123 | 8.724497523 | 1 | 65 |
| Downtown | 1 | APPAREL | JACKETS | LIGHT JACKET | F | OUT | abc123 | 8.724497523 | 2 | 100 |
| Downtown | 1 | APPAREL | PANTS | PANTS (1/1) | M | TRA | abc123 | 8.724497523 | 1 | 27.5 |
| Downtown | 1 | FOOTWEAR | SANDALS/SLIPPERS | SLIDES | M | RUN | abc123 | 8.724497523 | 1 | 17.5 |
| Downtown | 1 | APPAREL | TIGHTS | TIGHT LONG | F | TRA | abc123 | 8.724497523 | 2 | 35 |
| Coastal | 1 | APPAREL | PANTS | TRACK PANT | F | ORI | abc123 | 8.888442956 | 1 | 35 |
| Coastal | 1 | FOOTWEAR | SHOES | SHOES (LOW) | M | RUN | abc123 | 8.888442956 | 1 | 90 |
| Coastal | 1 | FOOTWEAR | SANDALS/SLIPPERS | SLIDES | M | RUN | abc123 | 8.888442956 | 1 | 17.5 |
| Coastal | 1 | FOOTWEAR | SHOES | SHOES (LOW) | U | ORI | abc123 | 8.888442956 | 1 | 55 |
| Coastal | 1 | APPAREL | PANTS | TRACK PANT | M | ORI | abc123 | 8.888442956 | 1 | 35 |
| Coastal | 1 | APPAREL | PANTS | PANTS (1/1) | M | TRA | abc123 | 8.888442956 | 1 | 27.5 |
| Coastal | 1 | FOOTWEAR | SHOES | SHOES (LOW) | M | ORI | abc123 | 8.888442956 | 1 | 65 |
| Coastal | 1 | APPAREL | JACKETS | LIGHT JACKET | F | OUT | abc123 | 8.888442956 | 2 | 100 |
| Coastal | 1 | APPAREL | SHORTS | SHORTS | M | TRA | abc123 | 8.888442956 | 3 | 50 |
| Coastal | 1 | APPAREL | PANTS | PANTS (1/1) | F | FOO | abc123 | 8.888442956 | 1 | 22.5 |
| Coastal | 1 | APPAREL | TIGHTS | TIGHT LONG | F | TRA | abc123 | 8.888442956 | 2 | 35 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is sor_hdr?
I think you need to drop the Partition by and replace row_number by rank

Comment: sor_hdr is supposed to be order_id. sorry, i fixed it

Comment: changing it to rank() made it so the number returned is the first row of each location grouping. i.e. if location Downtown starts on row 1 and goes through row 12, the value is 1. then coastal starts on 12 through 24 and so the value is 12. shouldn't it be 1, 2, 3, etc..?

Comment: ok, i see, change rank to dense_rank. At lease if i understand the requirements, that should do the trick

Comment: thanks! because there are instances where a customer could be the same distance from more than one location i need to use rank. dense_rank will make it assign the same rank to locations that are equidistant to the customer, which i don't want. if you want to edit your actual answer i'll mark it as solved :) thanks again!